# Auto creating div's with jQuery and inserting data from mysql

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I want to make auto creating div's with jQuery. I have to fill them with data from MySql database. The problem is that when I use foreach loop it doesn't want to echo data.

Here is my code for mysql:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `post` ORDER BY `id` DESC";
$result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
$row = mysqli_num_rows($result);
```

And here is my jQuery code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        var count = 1;
            for(i = <?php echo $row; ?>; i > 0; i--){
                $("#main").prepend('<div id="first'+count+'"></div>'); 
                count++;
            }
            count = 1;
            for(i = <?php echo $row; ?>; i > 0; i--){
                <?php
                    while($col = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
                        {
                            $cols[] = $col;
                        }
                    foreach($cols as $col){
                ?>
                $("#first"+count+"").text("<?php echo $col['post']; ?>");
                count++;
                <?php } ?>
            }
    });
```

I've also checked in inspect element and everything seems ok, but it doesnt want to create div's.

And if I change this **echo $col['post'];** to some other text, it works.

Here is what I get in inspect element:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        var count = 1;
            for(i = 3; i > 0; i--){
                $("#main").prepend('<div id="first'+count+'"></div>'); 
                count++;
            }
            count = 1;
            for(i = 3; i > 0; i--){
                                    $("#first"+count+"").text("text1");
                count++;
                                    $("#first"+count+"").text("text2");
                count++;
                                    $("#first"+count+"").text("text3");
                count++;
                                }
    });
```

Thank you for ideas!

Comment: well in the first run i would reduce the number of loops, you have a `for` loop, in it a `while` loop and then a `foreach` loop, one loop should be enough, for example a `while` loop which would iterate through the results

Comment: Yeah, thanks for suggestion but without all 3 loops it doesn't work as I want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I run your code in my workstation it works fine.

1. I can suggest you check for duplicate id of your new created div you can alter them in class may be its not conflict then.
2. Is #main div binded before the page load.
3. check for database is data insertion OK.

Its just some suggestion. If you can say some specific details about the scene, then i can provide you some specific suggestion.

Thanks

Comment: Thank you for suggestions... I've tried this code on localhost and it didn't work... Than I transfered the same code to my domain and it worked perfectly. I'm not sure why is so but it works as I wanted. Thanks anyway